# How to make github windows tool not checkout using EOL Ctrl-M characters

Tags: git, github

I checked out code from github using the github tool. Unfortunately, it checked out the files using Ctrl-M characters. In other version control tools e.g. SVN / Perforce, there used to be an option to make the tool checkout the text files in UNIX EOL mode. I don't see any option like this.
 I need to use the github windows tool to check out sources that I then later use via a linux VM but this issue is blocking it. The linux VM has no GUI and I need the GUI for diff and also ease of use when managing large files.

The only other option that I can think of is to pull / push / checkout branch from Linux using cmd line and *perhaps* just use windows GUI for diff .

Comment: Could you post an exact question, please? It's difficult to know what you are actually asking.

Comment: The question was to determine how to have control over whether github git tool checks out files with EOL or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `eol` in http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes, from where I quote:

```
End-of-line conversion While Git normally leaves file contents alone, it can be configured to normalize line endings to LF in the repository and, optionally, to convert them to CRLF when files are checked out.

Here is an example that will make Git normalize .txt, .vcproj and .sh files, ensure that .vcproj files have CRLF and .sh files have LF in the working directory, and prevent .jpg files from being normalized regardless of their content.

*.txt       text
*.vcproj    eol=crlf
*.sh        eol=lf
*.jpg       -text Other source code management systems normalize all text files in their repositories, and there are two ways to enable similar automatic normalization in Git.

If you simply want to have CRLF line endings in your working directory regardless of the repository you are working with, you can set the config variable "core.autocrlf" without changing any attributes.

[core]  autocrlf = true
```